# how to fix layout while displaying dynamic data from Database

Tags: php, html, css

I'm a beginner and trying to convert static data template to dynamic data.. Now I am facing a problem, where I have to use a for each loop to fetch data from array then display on certain divs..

There are 3 similar div containers but the third one has an additional class to move it to the right .. for eg: `(div1 => clas= "hello", div2 => class = "hello" , div3 => class = "hello floatrt" >)` .

The problem is my data is displayed but due the absense of class ="floatrt". My div's are being displayed vertically. but according to the static template design they are in a single row ..

How can I add class to the second or third or additional divs that are being generated from database.. but not the first div..

Comment: Take a look to the CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: show us what you have already. There are several ways to solve a problem like this. You can also use the nth-child() selector from css3 to add different styles to the Nth Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$count = 1;
foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
    // do anything here

    if ($count % 3 ==0) {
        echo '<div1 clas= "hello floatrt" ></div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div1 clas= "hello" ></div>';
    }


    $count++;
}
```